# Is there an eval() alternative for this expression?

Tags: javascript, eval

I have a string expression like such: `"1+2+3"`, and it must stay as a string. In other words, looping and casting the digits to perform the operation isn't an option, so my solution is `eval("1+2+3")`. But `eval()` is slow and has all these issues associated with it. Is there an alternative to evaluate my string?

Comment: Can that expression be built up by getting, for example, the "1", "2" and "3" as inputs?

Comment: You could write your own parser if you're feeling brave, or find something on [NPM](http://npmjs.com) that does it for you. `eval` isn't slow. It's just **trouble**.

Comment: If you can't loop and cast parts of the string to numbers, there are no other options, but that's what eval does here, it evaluates the expression in the string

Comment: anything simple is going to be too fragile to be useful (see answers below that can't handle `-1` or `1.1` for example), or it will be too complicated to handily implement ( ASTs, etc). use `eval` if you can.

Comment: @tadman can you explain what trouble can be caused?

Comment: It executes arbitrary code. That makes it extremely dangerous if it's used in the wrong context, for example, evaluating user-supplied strings.

Answer (score 2):

Evaluating a string is not only *slow*, it's *dangerous*. What if, by malicious user intent or error, you end up evaluating code that crashes your program, destroys your data o opens a security hole?

No, you should not `eval()` the string. You should split it, cast the operands to numbers, and sum them.

You can keep the `string` around if you like (you said you needed the string), but using the `string` to actually perform this operation is a **Really Bad Idea**.

```
var string = "1+2+3"
var numbers = string.split('+').map(function(x) { return parseInt(x) })
var sum = numbers.reduce(function(total, x) { return total + x }, 0)
```

Comment: OP: "_casting the digits to perform the operation isn't an option_"

Comment: It's what `eval` does. If you're going to call a function to do it, what's the difference?

Answer (score 0):

This is a silly question:

```
var reducer = function (a, b) { 
    return +a + +b; 
};

"1+2+3".match(/[+-]?\d+/g).reduce(reducer); // 6

// or addition only
"1+2+3".split(/\D/).reduce(reducer); // 6
```